# How to remove this Moen bathroom faucet cartridge?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, stuck, cartridge

I have been trying to remove this cartridge. I removed the copper nut and was advised by Moen support to try vinegar and threading a screw in to pull it out, but nothing has worked. I feel like there may be something obvious I don't know? Can anyone advise on ways I might be able to remove this cartridge or if I am missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a 1224 cartridge. Moen makes a cartridge puller sold separately where you'd buy the new cartridge. Before buying one try getting a large adjustable wrench 10" or an open end wrench and fit it over the two flat surfaces at the base of the cartridge and try turning it to break the seal between the cartridge and the valve base. They can be corroded together and difficult to separate. then try pulling up on the screw.